# Microsoft Teams Bot / 365 Connectors - Unable to save configuration

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I'm developing a Teams bot where i use 365 connectors.
Everything **works fine locally** and the connector is getting saved when using ngrok tunneling service.
The problem comes when i push the bot on production. All the functionallities are working except the part of connectors.
Also, the **validDomains** of the connector contains the **content_url** as it should. (XXX.services.com)

I receive the above error:

```
Received error from connectors {"seq":1608553736918,"timestamp":1608565625451,"flightSettings": 
 {"Name":"ConnectorFrontEndSettings","AriaSDKToken":"d127f72a3abd41c9b9dd94faca947689-d58285e6-3a68-4cab- 
 a458-37b9d9761d35- 
 7033","SPAEnabled":true,"ClassificationFilterEnabled":true,"ClientRoutingEnabled":true,"EnableYammerGroup 
 Option":true,"EnableFadeMessage":false,"EnableDomainBasedOwaConnectorList":false,"EnableDomainBasedTeamsC 
 onnectorList":false,"DevPortalSPAEnabled":true,"ShowHomeNavigationButtonOnConfigurationPage":false,"Disab  
 leConnectToO365InlineDeleteFeedbackPage":true},"status":500,"clientType":"SkypeSpaces","connectorType":"3   
 7bb22ee-bc38-45fe-80f4-02b0e778002b","name":"handleMessageError"}
```

Any ideas what i'm missing?

Comment: If you are trying the [react sample code for connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msteams-webhooks-connectors/7-exercise-o365-connectors) generated by yo teams, than i can confirm this is an known issue so please look at [teams-to-do connector sample code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-csharp/tree/master/TeamsToDoAppConnector)

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Thank's for your answer. I don't use the react sample code. 
Isn't that weird that everything works fine in my local environment using ngrok, but not on production server?

Comment: Is your production url contains any wildcard characters?

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Yes. Its something like.. **teams-service.XXX.XXX.com** . Would that cause my issue?

Comment: Yes, wildcard characters is not supported in connector configuration URL